# Using a date variable in a filename

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-excel

I have written a below mentioned code which export the Query into a Excel file.

```
 Public Function exportToXl11()
   Dim dbs As DAO.Database
   Set dbs = CurrentDb

   Dim sFilename As String

      sFilename = "c:\ExportFile\Output_Results.xlsx"

      DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "metrics2", acFormatXLSX, sFilename, Autostart:=False
End Function
```

I have another table name "Date1" which have date. I want a code which will export the query with a date given in a "Date1" table. Like the output will be "Output_results_23-05-2020.xlsx" instead of "Output_Results.xlsx"

Answer (score 1):

You can include the date in the filename variable:

```
sFilename = "c:\ExportFile\Output_Results_" & Format$(Now, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx"
```

You can format it any way you want, but make sure you do not include characters that are not allowed in filenames.

Comment: It should take date from the "Date1" table instead of Now

Comment: OK, then change it. You did not provide any information about that table, so I cannot give you specific code for it. Your question seems to actually be about how to get a date variable out of a table.

Comment: You didnt change anything that I can see, and you did not provide any information about the table in question. But it seems you are now changing the question. Is the real question "how do i get a value from a table?" Because my answer shows you how to add anything you want to the filename variable.

Comment: There is a Table called "Date1" which store Date like Date1.date='2020-05-31". The output of the file will be "Output_results_2020-05-31"